# Groovy Properties list from HashTable

Tags: list, groovy, hashtable

I am setting an external file to hold some persistent variables as Properties()

Is there an easy way to list these in the same way that

```
System.Properties()
```

does?? to produce a list of Properties I have set.

Answer (score 1):

try using config slurper

http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper

Comment: This looks an interesting route, but see below

Comment: I have 

    en = jr.keys()
    String list
    for(Enumeration e = en;
    e.hasMoreElements()
    ;){list = list + "\n" + jr.get(e.nextElement())
    }
    return list.replace('null\n', '')

but was looking to get a list of the key names that are current as opposed to those in the file

Answer (score 0):

System.Properties() is just an instance of java.util.Properties.

Take a look at the docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String list
for(Enumeration e = jr.keys();
e.hasMoreElements()
;){list = list + "\n" + e.nextElement()
}
return list.replace('null\n', '')
```

Is there a more Groovy way to do it??